# How to get validate select depending on another select

Tags: html, angular, types

I have a doctor list. And each doctor has his procedures. How can I apply selected doctor's procedures to procedures selection.

html

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="doctors">Doctor</label>
            <select [formControl]="selectControl" class="form-control" id="doctors">
                <option value="doctor"*ngFor="let doctor of doctors">{{doctor.username}}</option>
              </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="procedures">Select Procedure</label>
            <select *ngIf="selectControl.valid" class="form-control" id="procedures">
                <option *ngFor="let p of selectControl.value.procedures">{{p}</option>
              </select>
        </div>
```

.ts

```
selectControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
```

Answer (score 0):

For `select` control, the option value has to be binded to `[ngValue]` instead of `value` property.

Here is a working [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvbsbj) showing how to bind to `doctors` array and then how to retrieve the value of the `selectedProcedure`.

PS - Instead of creating a `formControl`, I personally find it more convenient to use [`formBuilder`](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) instead